# Reorganizing code based on dependencies

Tags: c, refactoring, dependency-analysis

I'm wondering if there is a tool that can generate a dependency graph between C language object files and then analyze how to turn that graph into a DAG by modifying code that creates cycles, moving it to other source files.

I've drawn a dependency graph by hand and I could probably make one by using makedepend or something similar, but the moving of functions also has to be done by hand.

Sorry if that's vague, but that's about the best I can describe it right now.

Comment: What do you mean by "moving the functions"? Do you want a tool to automatically modify source code for you?

Comment: Yes, the description is clearer now.

Answer (score 1):

There is a the [`Makefile.GraphViz`](http://search.cpan.org/~agent/Makefile-GraphViz-0.20/lib/Makefile/GraphViz.pm) perl module uses [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org/) to generate dependency graphs from `Makefile` rules. The documentation has an example of how to use it.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was looking more for something like [this](http://search.cpan.org/~agent/Makefile-Parser-0.215/lib/Makefile/Parser/GmakeDB.pm) or the associated AST module for generating dependencies. More than that though, I'm looking for a ready-made tool, if there is one.

Comment: And you can use gcc to generate the dependencies.